# XPATH - stop scraping after a certain html element

Tags: xpath

I am using this XPATH query to try grab the first three items from the "ASQ Package Price":

```
//h2[contains(., 'ASQ Package Features')]/following-sibling::p
```

But it also grabs  the other 3 items, so I end up with

Example 1
Example 2
Example 3
Example 4
Example 5
Example 6

I only want:

Example 1
Example 2
Example 3

How do I prevent XPATH from scraping the three I don't want - seems in this case it needs to stop at the `<hr>` tag?

```
<div itemprop="articleBody">

<h2>ASQ Package Price</h2>
<p class="">Example 1</p>
<p class="">Example 2</p>
<p class="">Example 3</p>

<hr>

<h2>ASQ Package Features&nbsp;</h2>

<p class="">Example 4</p>
<p class="">Example 5</p>
<p class="">Example 6</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
     (//h2[starts-with(., 'ASQ Package')])[1]/following-sibling::hr[1]
                                                         /preceding-sibling::p
```

---

**Verification with XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "(//h2[starts-with(., 'ASQ Package')])[1]
                    /following-sibling::hr[1]
                        /preceding-sibling::p"/>"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is run on the provided Html** (adjusted to be syntactically correct XHtml):

```
<html>
    <div itemprop="articleBody">
        <h2>ASQ Package Price</h2>
        <p class="">Example 1</p>
        <p class="">Example 2</p>
        <p class="">Example 3</p>
        <hr />
        <h2>ASQ Package Features&#160;</h2>
        <p class="">Example 4</p>
        <p class="">Example 5</p>
        <p class="">Example 6</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated, and all selected by it nodes are output**:

```
<p class="">Example 1</p>
<p class="">Example 2</p>
<p class="">Example 3</p>
```

---

**Explanation**:

We need the preceding-sibling `<p>` elements only of the first `<hr>` following-sibling of the first`<h2>` in the document, whose string value starts with `"ASQ Package"`, and

The first such `<h2>` element is selected by this XPath expression:

```
(//h2[starts-with(., 'ASQ Package Features')])[1]
```

Then we select its first following sibling `<hr>`:

```
    (//h2[starts-with(., 'ASQ Package Features')])[1]/following-sibling::hr[1]
```

Then we select all its preceding-sibling `<p>` elements:

```
 (//h2[starts-with(., 'ASQ Package')])[1]/following-sibling::hr[1]
                                                     /preceding-sibling::p
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath 2.0:

```
//h2/following-sibling::p intersect //hr/preceding-sibling::p
```

Using xpath 1.0:

```
//h2/following-sibling::p[not(preceding-sibling::hr)]
```